Copy pasting in Puppeteer
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    const context = await browser.createBrowserContext();

    await context.overridePermissions('', [
        'clipboard-read',
        'clipboard-write',
      ]);

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('');

    const { width, height } = page.viewport();

    await page.mouse.click(width / 2, height / 2);

    await page.keyboard.down('Control')
    await page.keyboard.press('a')
    await page.keyboard.up('Control')

    const copiedContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return navigator.clipboard.readText();
    });    

    fs.writeFileSync('code.txt', copiedContent);

    await browser.close();
})();

This is my current file. To copy and paste, I first accept those permissions, then I press down on the 'Control' key, press the 'A' key, and let go of the 'Control' key. Then, when I want to "paste" it into my file, it pastes off my clipboard correctly however the copying in my code did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What are you trying to achieve that requires copy-pasting in the first place?

I want to go to a site, it's just vscode browser environment with some lines of code that update.
